# Check how much storage space I have left on Google Docs

Tags: google-drive, online-storage

How do I check out how much storage space I have left with my Google Docs account?

Is there a page or indicator that will show me the quota I have remaining?

Answer (score 3):

Hit up the following site. It's in the middle, under "Storage": https://docs.google.com/settings?hl=en

Comment: slightly sarcastic, but correct.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the Settings icons - it looks like a cogwheel and may be on the top right-hand side of your screen. From the drop-down select Document Settings. On the left of the page that comes up look for Storage. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way of checking your storage use is via the [Google Drive storage summary](https://www.google.com/settings/storage/summary).